# Mechanical と Electrical の両方が入った環境で、Mechanical のインスタンスを指定する方法

Tags: c#, ijcad

Interop.GcadVbaLib を参照設定して C# より利用しようとしています。

IJCAD Mechanical のみがインストールされた環境においては、なにも問題なく動作しますが、Mechanical のほかに Electrical も入っている環境のとき、どちらもランセンス認証がされているにも関わらずライセンスを要求する画面が出現してしまいます。
　Mechanical のライセンス情報で Electrical のインスタンスを生成しようとしてしまっているのかもしれません。

Mechanical を指定して new GcadApplication() するにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

質問のエラーが再現できない状況です。

もし可能なら、以下の情報を教えてもらえませんか？
　・インストールしている IJCAD Mechanical のバージョン（★）
　・インストールしている IJCAD Electrical のバージョン（★）
　・IJCAD Electrical と IJCAD Mechanical をインストールした順番
　・参照していいる gcax.tlb のパス
　・質問のエラーが再現する簡単なコード

★「IJCADのバージョン」とは、ABOUTコマンドで確認できる「Build●●●●」のこと

よろしくお願いします。